# Google Sheets: Count if for multiple criteria + criteria over other range

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am actually counting accounts by active/deactivated by using the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('clients'!S2:S, "active*")
```

In this case, I am counting all the active accounts, totaling 8 active accounts,

```
Row S                   Row T
disabled: 14/02/2021    128
disabled: 23/02/2021    128
disabled: 23/02/2021    128
active: 23/02/2021      129
active: 02/02/2021      129
active: 23/02/2021      129
active: 23/02/2021      
active: 23/02/2021      130
active: 23/02/2021      130
disabled: 23/02/2021    
disabled: 23/02/2021    
disabled: 12/02/2021    
active: 23/02/2021  
active: 23/02/2021
```

But I want to add another constraint, I want to add only the rows that actually possess an ID, so the rows in column S that have an ID in column T will be the only ones counted, in that case, they will be totaling 5 active accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `"<>"` as the criteria for Row T to count all non-blank cells:

```
=countifs(S2:S,"active*",T2:T,"<>")
```

If only positive numbers are valid IDs, you could use `">0"` as the criteria for testing column T instead.

[image: image of solution and output]

Comment: Correct. Feel free to add the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5STbJ.png) as well